# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: torch

I have tried using @torch.compile before the def of my function but I obtained the AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'compile' .

I have installed torchtriton as in the tutorial. Any ideas?

I do not find any clues about similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that compile is **only available for PyTorch > 2.0** (https://pytorch.org/get-started/pytorch-2.0/)
Either you have to install PyTorch > 2.0 like this (but is unstable):

```
!pip3 install numpy --pre torch --force-reinstall --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu117
```

or just **delete the compile**. Compile only makes the model faster, but you should be able to train the model without compile and other PyTorch versions as well.